# Mongoose Validator Validate Length of Array After Push

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Below is my schema for `importantDates` which is an array of date objects with a `title` and the `importantDate`. The validator works correctly for the `title` and the `importantDate`, but I am also trying to validate the length of the array to only allow a max of 3 dates. I use `$push` to append to the array and when I do so, it is unable to validate the array length. I found through printing statements that `datesList` is only the value new entry and not the entire array, so how can I check the length of the array after a `$push` with just validators?

```
importantDates: {
  type: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        validate: [
          mongooseValidator({
            validator: (title) => 1 <= title.length && title.length <= 15,
            message:
              'Invalid important date title. Title must be between 1-15 characters',
          }),
        ],
      },
      importantDate: {
        type: String,
        validate: [
          mongooseValidator({
            validator: (importantDate) =>
              date.isValid(importantDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
            message:
              'Invalid important date. Must be in format of mm/dd/yyyy',
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  validate: [
    mongooseValidator({
      validator: (datesList) => {
        console.log(datesList);
        return datesList.length <= 3;
      },
      message:
        'Important dates have already reached a maximum of 3. Please remove some to add more.',
    }),
  ],
  default: [],
}
```

Comment: you need to make a query and get the length and use that length in validator.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I figured that that was going to be needed, but I was hoping that the validator would be able to do it, thanks though.

Comment: How can validator do that without looking the length in mongodb?